# How to constantly check expiration time in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

How to constantly check if token from sessionStorage has expired or not.

I have got the session expiration time from using the package `jsonwebtoken` .

and calculated the current time using this `new Date().getTime() / 1000;`

How to check this constantly if session has expired or not. How to run a function every time.

Your help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You won't check you token expiration in front-end, you can send you token along with any request to check it in back-end

Comment: yes...in my case..i need to validate the token ...when the session is active...if token expires...i need to logout the user. Not only on api calls..

Comment: Usually, the backend service do that for you when the token is expired, server will send a message via web socket to front, in front just listen to that message and then logout, but that is advanced stuff.

Comment: yeah ...i am doing that too..

Comment: What library did you use for socket?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare a `interval` ref that will check at each amount of time `checkHereForToken()`

---

```
  let interval = useRef(null);
  useEffect(() => {
     interval.current = setInterval(checkHereForToken, 1000);
     return () => clearInterval(interval.current);
  }, [])
```

Comment: did i need to call this function in App.js ?

Comment: you haven't attached your code so I can't answer for that, but this piece of code stand by itself so wherever you need to `checkHereForToken()` you can use it

Comment: Why don't you just call `checkHereForToken` in `setInterval` callback function?

Answer (score 1):

Call this below hook in a place your code is executed periodically (eg: App.js ), It will run continuously. You can change the time interval based on your need.

```
const CHECK_EXPIRATION_TIME_INTERVAL = 10000

export const useCheckExpirationTime = () => {

  let interval = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    interval.current = setInterval(
      () => checkExpirationTime(),
      CHECK_EXPIRATION_TIME_INTERVAL
    );
    return () => clearInterval(interval.current);
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, []);

  const checkExpirationTime = () => { /* PUT YOUR CODE HERE */ }
  
};
```

```
import React from "react";

import { useCheckExpirationTime } from "./useCheckExpirationTime";


function App() {

  useCheckExpirationTime();

  return (
      <> Hello World </>
  );
}
export default App;
```